# I can not connect to the ionic 3G application of a real device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, connection, ionic4

I am not able to connect to the ionic server using 3G from the cell phone, the wifi on which the machine is connected and the local browser I usually get, however when I disconnect the wifi restart the application with the 3G on it appears:

---

Application Error

### net :: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (http://192.168.15.45:8100/)

I'm new to ionic development, sorry for any mistakes I say, I'm not very good in English either, pardon my grammar mistakes.

Ionic info:

ionic (Ionic CLI): 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework: @ ionic / angular 4.0.1
   @ angular-devkit / angular build: 0.13.7
   @ angular-devkit / schematics: 7.2.4
   @ angular / cli: 7.2.4
   @ ionic / angular-toolkit: 1.4.0

Cordova:

Cordova (Cordova CLI): 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms: android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins: cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
   NodeJS: v11.9.0
   npm: 6.9.0
   OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you have is that you are pointing to a private IP (192.168.XX.XX) when you are in a public network, (157.32. XX) for the mobile application can connect to the end point of your private ip you must connect the mobile device to the private network, it can be through a router or other means.

Comment: Is there a way to get the device to connect to the private IP using the public network, I am using the windons as the ip operating system I do not know if this interferes with anything. Or if I need to open some network port, or allow something on the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Your device and computer where app is running should be on the same network/ip. If you can enable/share WIFI on your 3G running mobile/device and then connect your computer with it. Then you should be able to run App on your device.